# Example of an unbounded convex set with no recession direction?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-cone

Is it true that every unbounded convex set in $R^n$ has a recession direction? I think there is a counterexample, because I have not assumed that the convex set is closed.

I have not been able to come up with a counterexample though. Does anyone know if this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a finite dimensional space, any unbounded convex has a recession direction, should it be closed or not.

That may not be the case for infinite dimensional spaces though.

See [here](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/an-unbounded-convex-not-containing-a-ray/#more-338) for details.